# Google Assistant Production release got message: “For en: Your sample pronunciations are structured incorrectly.”

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Production release of Google Assistant not working.
It is always showing the message: "For en: Your sample pronunciations are structured incorrectly."

[image: For en: Your sample pronunciations are structured incorrectly.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have additional phrases setup correctly in the console. To do this

1. Select the Deploy tab along the top
2. Choose Directory Information on the left navigation
3. Make sure you have the English tab chosen, if you have multiple tabs
4. Open the Additional Invocation Phrases section
5. Make sure your additional phrases are in a valid form, or are filled in. This should be something like "Talk to..." or "Open..." followed by your invocation name.

Then resubmit your Action for approval.

[image: Directory Information - Additional Invocation Phrases]